# SharePoint2013: Error HTTP500 when creating collection site

Tags: iis, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, http-error

I have an Error HTTP 500 on my newest created collection site. *"http://sp-dev-2013:20000/site/Test"* with the administrator `sp13_Admin`

I've checked IIS application pool and all my Applications pool are up and started including `SecurityTokenServiceApplicationPool` and change the "identity field" with a `sp13_farm`. I did an **`iisreset`** command just in case but, it still doesn't work.

I've impersonated my AppPool Account `sp13_AppPool` in Local Security Policy and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check in the Sharepoint ULS log files to get more information about the error?